# ducplicate key error when copying mysql database with add constraint error

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am trying to copy a mysql database.

What is the add_constraint option ?

When I select this option, I get a duplicate key error.

When I check, there is no duplicate key in the initial sql statement that allowed me to create the original database in the first place.

any insight appreciated :)

Comment: Can you share your query?

Comment: well, it's a full database copy. i've just unchecked add_constraint and it works fine and keeps the existing keys